# Copying multiple files to hosts using ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

I have four different hosts.
host1, host2, host3, host4

I am trying to update following files on the these hosts.

```
host1
/var/www/foo1

host2
/var/www/foo1
/var/tmp/foo1

host3
/var/www/foo1

host4
/var/tmp/foo1
```

I am able to write two different playbook with different inventory files and group vars to achieve this task.

**Inventory file 1**

```
[group_foo1]
host1
host2
host3
```

**Group variable**

File name: group_foo1

```
path:/var/www
```

**Inventory file 2**

```
[group_foo2]
host2
host4
```

**Group variable**

File name: group_foo2

```
path:/var/tmp
```

**Task**

```
name: copy the file
copy: src=foo1 dest={{path}}
```

I want to do this task using single playbook.

How it can be done?

Comment: Setup a vars file to include in your playbook.  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/index.html is a great resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [synchronize module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html):

```
# Synchronize two directories on one remote host.
synchronize:
    src: /first/absolute/path
    dest: /second/absolute/path
delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

ALso you can try to  iterate in a tasks over all hosts:

```
with_items: groups['all']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in a single playbook and target the tasks to different hosts in one of the following ways:

##### 1. Define groups in your Ansible inventory file and delegate tasks to specific hosts:

Put your hosts in groups, e.g.:

```
[www_hosts]
host1
host2
host3

[tmp_hosts]
host2
host4
```

And setup your playbook to delegate tasks to these groups like this:

```
- name: Copy the file to www_path
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "foo1"
    dest: "/var/www"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['www_hosts'] }}"

- name: Copy the file to tmp_path
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "foo1"
    dest: "/var/tmp"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['tmp_hosts'] }}"
```

Don't forget to set the `run_once` to `true` otherwise the same tasks will run (and be delegated to each host) on each host you target the playbook.

##### 2. Setup variables as a condition to run tasks on specific hosts:

If you don't want your playbook to be dependent on a specific inventory setup you can also set it up in a variables file or section and run tasks selectively. E.g.:

Set up a `vars/main.yml` file (or vars-section) with:

```
www_hosts:
 - host1
 - host2
 - host3

tmp_hosts:
 - host2
 - host4
```

Make sure these vars gets loaded into your playbook/role and setup playbook tasks like this:

```
- name: Copy the file to www_path
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "foo1"
    dest: "/var/www"
  when: ansible_fqdn in www_hosts

- name: Copy the file to tmp_path
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "foo1"
    dest: "/var/tmp"
  when: ansible_fqdn in tmp_hosts
```